# Fetching one element of array with sibling items (Without using aggregation or putting other sibling's value 1)

Tags: mongodb, nosql

```
"translation" : [ 
    {
        "language" : "english",
        "name" : "shahid Afridi",
        "desc" : "batsmen",
        "player" : "capten"
    }, 
    {
        "language" : "spanish",
        "name" : "shhid Ofridi",
        "desc" : "batsmeen",
        "player" : "capteen"
    }, 
    {
        "language" : "french",
        "name" : "hhid afrede is best",
        "desc" : "batsmin",
        "player" : "captn"
    }
],
    "auto-publish" : "publish",
    "color" : "red",
    "boolean" : "true"
```

I have this document in mongodb
In return
i want translation[0] with auto-publish, color and boolean.
Note: Without using aggregation or putting other sibling's value 1

Comment: Please mention your MongoDB version? Also mention reason you don't want to use aggregation framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach on your cursor:

```
db.test.find({}).forEach(function(doc){
    if (doc.hasOwnProperty('translation')){
        var newdoc = {};
        newdoc = doc.translation[0];
        newdoc['auto-publish'] = doc['auto-publish'];
        newdoc['color'] = doc['color'];
        newdoc['boolean'] = doc['boolean'];        
        print(tojson(newdoc));
    }
})
```

I don't think there's any other way to re-organize document as you need without using aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it is equivalent to putting other sibling field's value 1. I am not preferring this because if we have 100 fields, so we have to put 1 in 100 or the way you tried newdoc[' '] = doc[' '] to 100 fields.

Comment: Well, i think aggregation is the only way to get needed result without putting values or equals one doc field to another. Why don't you want to use aggregation?